# Is it possible to view PE headers in xdbg just like ollydbg?

Tags: debugging, ollydbg

In ollydbg you can view the PE header of a module, by going into memory map and double clicking on the PE headers, but i couldn't find a way to do this in XDBG, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pex64dbg](https://github.com/horsicq/pex64dbg) plugin, but that will only show you view of the main module. It looks like this:

[image: PE Viewer]